# in Java, How do I peek() the top k elements in a PriorityQueue ?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I see in the documentation,
that [PriorityQueue.peek()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#peek%28%29) gives me access to the head of the queue in O(1),   but what if I need access to the k top elements in the queue ?
 I would use `poll()` k times, but that takes O(log(N)) , is there a way to do it in constant time ?

Comment: Not with `PriorityQueue` alone, no. There is only one top element.

Comment: Do you just need access to the elements or remove them from the queue ?

Comment: @SushilDhaundiyal just access.

Comment: Actually it takes O(k log N) time (O(log N) per element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not possible to do it in constant time.** If your data is already in a `PriorityQueue`, removing the top k elements one by one is the best you can do. [Each remove costs you `O(log(n))`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12719066/341970) but you have also figured that one out, hence the question.

However, if you are not forced to use a `PriorityQueue`, then you can do a *partial sort* on a list and retrieve the top k elements. The asymptotic complexity of a partial sort is `O(n*log(k))`. It can be executed faster than the `PriorityQueue` approach if we also take into account the cost of setting up the priority queue, see [Selecting top k items from a list efficiently in Java / Groovy](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/selecting-top-k-items-from-a-list-efficiently-in-java-groovy) (select the top 5 elements from a list of 10 million, PriorityQueue 300ms vs. partial sort 170ms).

Answer (score 8):

Nope. If you could do it in constant time, you could do a comparison sort in linear time by heapifying an array and then finding the top N items, where N is all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The programming question ([link](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000435bae/0000000000887dba)) where I needed a similar functionality:

> The question was related to having a list of parties (lets assume)
> that had a start time and end time and happiness value. We need to
> select a maximum of k parties at a given time so that the sum of those
> parties has maximum happiness value.

One way would be to use **2 priority queues -> 1 max heap and 1 min heap of size k**. When a new event comes and the min heap has less than k elements I add it into the min heap, or if the min heap is full and the top is greater then I add it to the secondary max heap, or if the min heap is full and the top is smaller then add the new one onto min heap and the smaller one from min onto max heap. In this process I keep the sum of top k elems consistent and I get it in O(1), in your case the elements too can be got in O(1).

**Note**: I went ahead with 2 TreeMaps itself as it was best suited for my usecase, explained with heap because it might be easier to understand/visualize.

So this is what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in `O(klogk)` time and `O(k)` additional space if the input is represented as an indexed sequence in heap order. If `k << n`, that's a very good improvement.

```
static List <Integer> kLargest(List<Integer> xs, int k) {
 if (k <= 0) return Collections.emptyList();

 PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> pq = 
    new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue));

 pq.add(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(0, xs.get(0)));
 List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  Map.Entry <Integer, Integer> max = pq.remove();
  result.add(max.getValue());

  int j = max.getKey();
  int left = 2 * j + 1;
  int right = 2 * j + 2;

  if (left < xs.size()) pq.add(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(left, xs.get(left)));
  if (right < xs.size()) pq.add(new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(right, xs.get(right)));
 }
 return result;
}
```

The question is, how to get the input in heap order. If you create your own `PriorityQueue` class, you'll obviously have access to the internal array.