# How do I use a TreeSet in Java that allows Duplicates?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue, treeset

I want a data structure with priority queue functions in O(logn) time and also be able to delete a specific element that's not necessarily the head in O(logn) time. I heard the TreeSet in java does  it but does not allow Duplicates, How do i get around this?

Comment: For example you can add a running ID to make sure you have no duplicates

Comment: The *entire point* of a set, in Java or anywhere else, is that it doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: If you want to insert duplicates then create a datastructure and insert its object.In this way it allows duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Use **[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)** which allows insertion in `log n` time and deletion in `log n` time. You can have there `TreeMap<Integer,Integer>` where key stores the value of element and value stores the frequency of the element.

If you need to do only `Insert` and `Delete` operation , Use Java's **[Priority Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)**. It also allows insertion in `log n` time and deletion in `log n` time as it uses `Heaps` to store the data.

You can do `Insertion`, `Deletion` by implementing the functions for `TreeMap`.

```
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map=new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

**Insertion :**

```
public boolean insert(int value) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        if(!map.containsKey(value))
            map.put(value,0);

        map.put(value,map.get(value)+1);

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Head of the queue(peek) :**

```
public int getHead()
{
    if(map.firstKey()==null)
        return null;

    return (int)map.firstKey();
}
```

**Remove and retrieve head(poll) :**

```
public int removeHead() 
{
    if(getHead()==null)
        return null;

    int head=getHead();

    if(map.get(head)==1)
        map.remove(head);
    else
        map.put(head,map.get(head)-1);
}
```

Comment: `insert` can be implemeted as just `map.merge(value, 1, Integer::sum)`, `removeHead` would be more efficient with `map.compute()`

Comment: This answer is incorrect, because the question says delete a specific element in `O(logn)` time. Not just the head. PriorityQueue can delete ONLY head in `O(logn)` time. For a generic element deletion it takes `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so i'll say this here. I think that removing an element in a priorityqueue is O(N) as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719066/priority-queue-remove-complexity-time).

You might be able to get around this in some cases. If you don't plan on adding an object after removing it, you could make a wrapper around the priorityqueue and keep a hashSet of removed elements. Then, if you come across that object when polling, you discard it.

You could also create your own priorityqueue using an ordered list. You could then use a binary search to find insert positions or the index to remove efficiently.