# Java - TreeSet accepting duplicates

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

I'm having some problems with TreeSet: why does this one accept duplicates? I thought TreeSets detected them through the Comparator, and automatically remove them. Please help me, I'm kind of new to both Java and StackOverflow.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SortedSongs
{   
    private Set songs;
    public SortedSongs()
    {
         Comparator<Song> comp = (Song c1, Song c2)-> c1.toString().compareTo(c2.toString());
         songs = new TreeSet<>(comp);
    }
}
```

edit: this is how I implemented hashCode and equals:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return Objects.hash(name, author);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    return o == null ? false : o.getClass() != getClass() ? false
        : o.hashCode() == hashCode();
}
```

edit2:
This is the updated equals method, toString and compareTo for class Song

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (this==o) return true;
    if (getClass()!=o.getClass()) return false;
    return name.equals(((Song) o).name) && author.equals(((Song) o).author);
}
@Override
public String toString() {return name + " - " + author;}

public int compareTo(Song other)
{
    if (name.equals(other.name))
        return author.equals(other.author) ? 0 : author.compareTo(other.author);
    return name.compareTo(other.name);
}
```

So now the Comparator in SortedSongs

```
Comparator<Song> comp = (Song c1, Song c2)-> c1.compareTo(c2);
```

Still not working though, I feel as if I'm missing something obvious

edit3:
Solved, I actually made a mistake with my Test class. Embarrassing. Sorry, didn't mean to waste your time, I hope this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: They use hash code and equals to see if in the set.

Comment: The issue may be a bit subtle: You are comparing the songs by their string representation. You should show us how `toString` is implemented, and preferably also show which `Song` objects end up as duplicates. In general, the comparator has to be *consistent with equals* to obey the contract of the `Set` interface, but even without a proper `equals` implementation, you should not see duplicates.

Comment: (And a side note: Your current `equals` implementation is **not** valid. The general rule is: **If** objects are equal according to the `equals` method, **then** they must have the same `hashCode`. But if they have the same `hashCode`, then they are *not necessarily* equal according to the `equals` method. Only a side note, because it *should* not be relevant for the issue that you are observing)

Comment: Your `equals` and `Comparator<Song>` are not quite correct. Try to fix them first so that they compare `Song`s field by field.

Comment: The equals method is absolutely wrong.  Joshua Bloch tells you how to override equals and hashCode correct in chapter 3 of "Effective Java".

Comment: Please add code for method `toString()` in class `Song`

Comment: What are the fields, `name` and `author`? Also, can you give an example of some input that is causing it to fail?

Comment: Fields of Song are two strings, name and author.

Answer (score 5):

`TreeSet` is implemented with a balanced binary tree in Java (actually RedBlack tree) . So it does not use the `equals` method. It uses the `Comparator`.

Now the problem about your implementation is about your `comparator`.
Your comparator is based on the `toString` method. By default java returns the name of the object's class plus its hash code. So by default the output of `toString` will be the same for two objects if and only if they are pointing to the same memory reference. You need to make sure that you have override the `toString` method in your class as you comparator is based on that.

To resolve the issue, you need to define a comparator that reflect the comparison logic of your program.

Comment: The issue is clearly related to `toString`, but as long as we don't know whether (or how) `toString` was overridden, it's hard to give a definite answer here. According to the name (`SortedSongs`), I'm pretty sure that there is a `toString` implementation, and the intention was to sort the songs alphabetically - but that's also just a guess until now..

Comment: **Don't use `toString()` at all** (for _anything_, _ever_). Make the `Comparator` do its own work without any help from `toString()`, looking directly at whatever data comprises a `Song`-- title, writer, singer, arranger, whatever -- then in won't matter whether `toString()` is right or wrong, overridden or not..

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` delegates under the hood to `TreeMap` implementation with dummy values.
So, instead of allowing duplicates with tricky comparator, it would be easier and more memory-efficient to switch to TreeMap with values holding duplicate counts.

Here is an example: [How do I use a TreeSet in Java that allows Duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851149/how-do-i-use-a-treeset-in-java-that-allows-duplicates).